# What does depth mean in a 1-dimensional neural network?

Tags: deep-learning

Can some explain to me what depth means in the context a 1-D CNN? I understand that in a one one image the depth = 3 (RGB), but suppose you simply had a graph of n values equally spaced along an x axis.  What would the depth be then?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry word predict when wrong .I meant to say in an 2-D image the depth =3

Comment: You can edit your post.